YugabyteDB Table system.peers_v2 not found: OBJECT_NOT_FOUND using Java YCQL driver
My yb-tserver is throwing lots error similar to this:

72 client_master_rpc.cc:76] 0x000055bb709bca98 -> GetTableSchemaRpc(table_identifier: table_name: "peers_v2" namespace { name: "system" database_type: YQL_DATABASE_CQL }, num_attempts: 1): Failed, got resp error: Not found (yb/master/catalog_manager.cc:5246): Table system.peers_v2 not found: OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (master error 3

Using yb-master/yb-tserver version: yugabytedb/yugabyte:2.18.2.1-b1
Currently using java driver:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.yugabyte</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0-yb-10</version>
</dependency>



The driver that you're using is a bit old:
https://github.com/yugabyte/cassandra-java-driver/releases/tag/4.6.0-yb-10
You should upgrade to the latest driver and these errors should vanish.
The peers_v2 error could happen -- newer (vanilla) Cassandra version introduced a peers_v2 table instead of the peers one (with some more/better data on the nodes).
Newer Cassandra drivers will query that to check if it exists and then go back to using peers if it doesn't (the key info is on both of them).
